# tkinter window behaves have different height when imported

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, tkinter, notifications

I wrote a Tkinter-based module to mimic notifications from zoom meetings. I am currently working on windows. However, when importing it into my main code, the notification shows a different height:

when executed directly,
[image]

when imported,
[image: imported execution sample]

My code, main class is Notification, skip there to save time:

```py
import tkinter as tk

def round_rectangle(canvas, x1, y1, x2, y2, radius, **kwargs):
    width = x2 - x1
    height = y2 - y1
    if radius > min(width, height):
        radius = min(width, height)

    points = [x1 + radius, y1,
              x1 + radius, y1,
              x2 - radius, y1,
              x2 - radius, y1,
              x2, y1,
              x2, y1 + radius,
              x2, y1 + radius,
              x2, y2 - radius,
              x2, y2 - radius,
              x2, y2,
              x2 - radius, y2,
              x2 - radius, y2,
              x1 + radius, y2,
              x1 + radius, y2,
              x1, y2,
              x1, y2 - radius,
              x1, y2 - radius,
              x1, y1 + radius,
              x1, y1 + radius,
              x1, y1]

    canvas.create_polygon(points, **kwargs, smooth=True)
    return canvas

class Dragpad(tk.Canvas):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Canvas.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        # drag around
        self.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", self.start_move, add='+')
        self.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.stop_move, add='+')
        self.bind("<B1-Motion>", self.do_move, add='+')

    def start_move(self, event):
        self.x = event.x
        self.y = event.y

    def stop_move(self, event):
        self.x = None
        self.y = None

    def do_move(self, event):
        deltax = event.x - self.x
        deltay = event.y - self.y
        x = self.master.winfo_x() + deltax
        y = self.master.winfo_y() + deltay
        self.master.geometry(f"+{x}+{y}")

class FadeAway(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Toplevel.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        # default opacity:
        self.opacity = 0.7

        # ask Windows to ignore this window
        self.overrideredirect(True)
        self.wm_overrideredirect(True)

        # reset bomb
        self.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", self.end_countdown, add='+')
        self.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.start_countdown, add='+')

        # fade away
        self.bomb = self.after(3000, self.fade_away)

    def end_countdown(self, event):
        if self.bomb:
            self.after_cancel(self.bomb)
        self.attributes('-alpha', self.opacity)

    def start_countdown(self, event):
        self.bomb = self.after(3000, self.fade_away)

    def fade_away(self, speed=0.01):
        alpha = self.attributes("-alpha")
        if alpha > 0:
            alpha -= speed
            self.attributes("-alpha", alpha)
            self.bomb = self.after(10, self.fade_away)
        else:
            self.destroy()

class Notification(FadeAway):
    def __init__(self, text="", fontsize=25, *wargs, **kwargs):
        FadeAway.__init__(self, wargs, kwargs)

        # ask Windows to ignore this window
        self.overrideredirect(True)
        self.wm_overrideredirect(True)

        # layering
        self.attributes("-topmost", True)

        # location and size
        line_count = text.count('\n') + 1
        margin = 20
        width = 2 * margin + int(self.winfo_screenwidth() / 2)
        height = int(2 * margin + fontsize * line_count + 0.75 * fontsize * (line_count - 1)) + 10
        x_cor = int(self.winfo_screenwidth() / 2 - width / 2)
        y_cor = int(self.winfo_screenheight() - 300 - height)

        self.geometry("{}x{}+{}+{}".format(  # width, height, x-cor, y-cor
            width,
            height,
            x_cor,
            y_cor
        ))

        # constant
        radius = 100
        dragpad_width = 50
        dragpad_color = "#0d0d0d"

        # design
        self.configure(bg='blue')
        self.wm_attributes('-transparentcolor', 'blue')  # set blue as transparent
        self.opacity = 0.7
        self.attributes('-alpha', self.opacity)

        # background
        self.background = tk.Canvas(self, width=width - dragpad_width, height=height, highlightthickness=0)
        self.background.configure(bg="blue")
        self.background.pack(side="right")
        self.background.configure(bg="blue")
        round_rectangle(self.background, dragpad_width, 0, width - dragpad_width, height, radius=radius, fill="black")

        # dragpad
        self.dragpad = Dragpad(self, width=dragpad_width, height=height, highlightthickness=0)
        self.dragpad.configure(bg="blue")
        self.dragpad.pack(side="left", fill="y")
        round_rectangle(self.dragpad, 0, 0, dragpad_width + radius, height, radius=radius, fill=dragpad_color)

        # text
        self.label = tk.Label(self.background, text=text,
                              height=height,
                              bg='black',
                              fg="white",
                              font=("Courier", fontsize),
                              padx=margin + 20, pady=margin,
                              justify="left",
                              anchor="nw",
                              )
        self.label.place(x=-10,y=-5,)


class Notifier:
    _window = None
    @classmethod
    def notify(cls, text, font):
        if cls._window:
            cls._window.destroy()
        cls._window = Notification(text, font)


def tk_notify(text="1\n2\n3",font=15):
    Notifier.notify(text, font)

def main():
    tk_notify("bruh")
    root.after(5000, tk_notify, "am i a joke?")
    root.after(10000, root.destroy)


root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root.after(1000, main)
    root.mainloop()
    print("ended")
```

import code:

```py
from tk_notify import tk_notify

tk_notify("testing...\nscript ready")
```

I would like to make it behave the same whether imported or not, I checked the `height` variable but both give 71 on my pc. the pictures are 100% unedited screenshots.

As a Tkinter beginner, I would also appreciate it if someone could provide suggestions for my code. thanks beforehand

Comment: I got same output (first image) for both cases.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you Have to set a defined size, but do not have a particular length like height in particular or width in particular. If this is a MessageBox you may not be able to change the size.